# Converting shapefile to KML using GeoTools?

Tags: shapefile, kml, geotools

I am developing a GIS-based desktop tool for a land area in geotool.

How we can convert shapefile into KML file?

Answer (score 1):

You read in the shapefile using a shapefile datastore and write out the KML using a KML datastore.

Comment: While correct, a better answer would include some kind of sample code or a link to a relevant sample...